# MySQL - Find SUM using Triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am new to triggers(and MySQL) and I am trying to update the field "likes"(with the sum of likes for this post) in my "posts" table each time that an entry is added on "likes" table. How I will accomplish that?

post table: user_id,likes,comment...
likes table: user_id, post_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this in your trigger.

```
UPDATE posts SET likes=likes+1 WHERE ID=new.post_id
```

So you update your table posts, likes=likes+1 where your post ID equals the new(like).post_id.

EDIT: in a trigger things like new, deleted, updated etc refer to the row that fired the trigger.

Please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html for more details

EDIT: This does not completely answer your question. To answer your question, i'd set up a cron job which runs once per day/week/month to refresh the number of likes placed in a post.

Comment: So I should insert this using phpmyAdmin: table:likes, time:after, event:insert definition: update posts...., definer: ?

Comment: should I create another one trigger for "unlike"?

Comment: Yes you should create a trigger for unlikes. Please play around a little in PHPMyAdmin, I'm also an amateur who had to figure it all out myself, which I did. Failure is your college.

Comment: I found it! thank you but I have another question. For Delete what I should put here "ID=new.post_id"

Comment: Deleted or old, I do not know for sure.

Comment: It's old.post_id. Thanks a lot